# $\mathbb{E}\big(e^{X}\big|$ $e^{Y}\big)\overset{?}{=}\mathbb{E}\big(e^{X}\big|$ $Y\big)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, moment-generating-functions

I have a quick question. Is the following reasoning correct? If not, why?

I know that $X|Y\in N(\rho Y, 1-\rho^2)$.

I want to deduce an expression for $\mathbb{E}\big(e^{X}\big|$ $e^{Y}\big)$. My idea was as following:

$\mathbb{E}\big(e^{X}\big|$ $e^{Y}\big)\overset{?}{=}\mathbb{E}\big(e^{X}\big|$ $Y\big)=M_{X|Y}(1)=e^{\rho Y+\frac{1}{2}(1-\rho^2)}$

where $M_{X|Y}$ is the moment generating function for $X|Y$.

I know that the expression that I got at the end is correct. I guess that what I'm really asking is whether my reasoning is correct and if a continuous function of a random variable $X$ is $X$-measurable?

Comment: Why do you equate a number to a set (which is weirdly defined)?

Comment: Where am I equating a number to a set?

Comment: Read through your question. You'll find it...

Comment: I really cannot find it. I have updated the question. Do I still equate a number to a set somewhere?

Comment: Then what do you mean by $\{e^Y\text{ is $Y$-measurable}\}$?

Comment: Oh, that's just a sloppy notation indicating my way of reasoning. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, provided that $e^{X}$ is integrable. It is because $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(e^{Y})$.

Proof: Clearly $e^{Y}$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, so $\sigma(e^{Y})\subseteq\sigma(Y)$.
On the other hand, $Y=\ln\left(e^{Y}\right)$ which is $\sigma(e^{Y})$-measurable,
so $\sigma(Y)\subseteq\sigma(e^{Y})$.